# Isolated scope variable of directive is undefined

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to access a variable of a controller from a directive but the variable is undefined and I can't figure out why. The variable is undefined immediately on page load which is I'd guess is because the html is loaded before the controller is initialised but I don't understand how it's undefined afterwards when the html is loaded and renderTimetable is called.

```
angular.module('app')
       .directive('timetable',

function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            bookings: '=',
            timetableDate: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

                scope.$watch('bookings', function(updatedBookings, unupdatedBookings) {
                    if (typeof updatedBookings !== 'undefined') {
                        console.log(scope.timetableDate); // undefined
                        scope.renderTimetable(updatedBookings);
                    }
                });

                // bookings

                scope.renderTimetable = function(planes) {

                    console.log(scope.timetableDate); // undefined
                }
            };
        }
    };
});
```

And the directive has attribute set with controller's scope:

```
<timetable bookings="bookings" timetableDate="timetableDate"></timetable>
```

The timetableDate model binded like so:

```
<input readonly datepicker ng-model="timetableDate" value="timetableDate" />
```

In the controller the variable is set immediately, console.log gets a date string as expected:

```
...
    function($scope, $http, $location, $interval) {
        $scope.bookingModalVisible = false;
        $scope.timetableDate = new Date().toDateString();
        console.log(timetableDate); // NOT undefined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
<timetable bookings="bookings" timetableDate="timetableDate"></timetable>
```

to

```
<timetable bookings="bookings" timetable-date="timetableDate"></timetable>
```

From [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#normalization):

> Angular normalizes an element's tag and attribute name to determine
>   which elements match which directives. We typically refer to
>   directives by their case-sensitive camelCase normalized name (e.g.
>   ngModel). However, since HTML is case-insensitive, we refer to
>   directives in the DOM by lower-case forms, typically using
>   dash-delimited attributes on DOM elements (e.g. ng-model).